# Unable to copy Elasticache backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elasticache

I have followed those instructions step by step: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-exporting.html

However I have the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CopySnapshot operation: Elasticache was unable to validate the authenticated user has access on the S3 bucket ...
```

The bucket is in the same region of the backup

This is my bucket configuration:

```
{
    "LocationConstraint": "eu-central-1"
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "xxxxxxxx",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "eu-central-1.elasticache-snapshot.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the snapshot

```
{
    "Snapshots": [
        {
            "SnapshotName": "my-snapshot-name",
            "CacheClusterId": "xxxxxxxx-xxx",
            "SnapshotStatus": "available",
            "SnapshotSource": "manual",
            "CacheNodeType": "cache.t2.micro",
            "Engine": "redis",
            "EngineVersion": "5.0.3",
            "NumCacheNodes": 1,
            "PreferredAvailabilityZone": "eu-central-1c",
            "CacheClusterCreateTime": "xxxxxxx",
            "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "mon:02:30-mon:03:30",
            "Port": 6379,
            "CacheParameterGroupName": "default.redis5.0",
            "CacheSubnetGroupName": "internal",
            "VpcId": "xxxxx",
            "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade": true,
            "SnapshotRetentionLimit": 7,
            "SnapshotWindow": "00:00-02:00",
            "NodeSnapshots": [
                {
                    "CacheNodeId": "0001",
                    "CacheSize": "33 MB",
                    "CacheNodeCreateTime": "xxxxxx",
                    "SnapshotCreateTime": "xxxxxx"
                }
            ],
            "ARN": "arn:aws:elasticache:eu-central-1:000000000:snapshot:my-snapshot-name",
            "DataTiering": "disabled"
        }
    ]
}
```

### UPDATE

Apparently AWS updated their docs by adding a crucial piece of information regarding the ACL, look the accepted answer for more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here very important step is to add ACL as mentioned in doc:

Add grantee Canonical Id **540804c33a284a299d2547575ce1010f2312ef3da9b3a053c8bc45bf233e4353** with the following options:

- **Objects: List, Write**
- **Bucket ACL: Read, Write**

[image]

> **I added this ACL permission and it started working like a charm.**

After adding this ACL my configuration looks below.
[image]
[image]

Full Ref document link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-exporting.html#backups-exporting-grant-access

Comment: "as mentioned in the docs": this was not mentioned at all in the docs 7 months ago, it was recently updated 3 months ago.

Comment: why the aws guys make the s3 bucket so complicated?

Comment: please notice that this approach may failed sometime~ when you met the same problem, just re-create the bucket , then try again. ( I tried 5 times and succeeded )

Answer (score 0):

Based on the article you linked, you also need additional S3 permission:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }]
}
```

Have you verified that your IAM user has these access?

Comment: Yes, I do have full access

Answer (score 0):

When you create the S3 bucket, enable ACLs. Then you can continue with the Permissions section of the instructions.

[image]